# no torsion elements in a specific finitely presented group?

Tags: group-theory

I'm trying to prove, or to find a counter example, of the following: Assume we have a group $G$, generated by $x_1,...,x_n$ such that $G/G' \cong \mathbb{Z}^n$. Let $G_1 \doteq G/\langle x_1 = 1 \rangle$. We know that $G_1$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of a free abelian group and free groups, i.e. $G_1 \cong \mathbb{Z}^m + \mathbb{F}_{r_1} + ... + \mathbb{F}_{r_k}$ for some $m,r_1,...,r_k \geq 0$. In particular, we know that there are no torsion elements in  $G_1$.

Does this mean that $G$ also does not have torsion elements?

Edit: In $G$, the only allowed relations between the generators are $[x_i,x_j]=1$ and $[x_i,x_jx_k]=1$ (where $j \neq k$).

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: Your group is torsion-free.  The only torsion could live in $G'$, so we would need an element $z$, in the free group on the $x_i$, which lived in the commutator subgroup, and which had a proper power that was in the relator subgroup.  But your relators are all basically primitive (generators for the commutator subgroup), so this doesn't happen.  Note that if $[x_i,x_j]=1$, then $[x_i,x_jx_k]=1$ is equivalent to $[x_i,x_k]=1$.

Comment: thanks! so in fact the data on $G_1$ is redundant here, right? However, I should note that $G$ can be with only the relations $[x_1,x_2]=1$ and $[x_3,x_4x_5]=1$ (i.e. there isn't necessarily a relation of the form $[x_1,x_2x_j]=1$ for some $j$. Does this cause any problems? (I don't think so, but just to be sure).

Comment: No, it doesn't cause any problems. And yes the data on $G_1$ is reduntant.  All you need is the form for the possible relators you gave.  If $F$ is the free group on the $x_i$, then you are concerned with torsion in $[F,F]/R$, where $R$ is the relator subgroup.  But $[F,F]$ is generated by $[x_i,x_j]$ and their conjugates.  So a relator of the form $[x_i,x_j]$ kills a generator, while a relator of the form $[x_i,x_jx_k]=[x_i,x_k][x_i,x_j]^{x_k}$ identifies two generators.  So  $G'$ is torsion free.

Comment: ok, thanks. so in fact, I guess that even if allow that $G$ will have also relations of the form $[x_i,x_jx_kx_j^{-1}]=1$ (where $i,j,k$ all different), that won't cause any problems either? though I guess that in this case $G'$ will not be free group any more.

Comment: Actually you've got to be careful, and I corrected my comment: $G'$ does not have to be free. To see what can go wrong, consider your group to be generated by $x_1,\ldots,x_4$, with relations $[x_1,x_2]=[x_2,x_3]=[x_3,x_4]=[x_4,x_1]=1$.  The commutator is not a free group.

Comment: why's that, actually? don't you get only that the corresponding generators are sent to $1$ in $G'$?

Comment: The problem is the following: $x_1$ and $x_3$ commute with both $x_2$ and $x_4$.  As a result, $[x_1,x_3]$ commutes with $[x_2,x_4]$. The group is still torsion-free, but in $G'$ you might get relators that live in $G''$, as above.  In other words, you might get some direct products, rather than free products.

Comment: I see. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps I am missing something, but if $G$ is defined by generators and relations as
\begin{equation}
G = \langle x_1, x_2, y : [x_1, x_2] = y, [x_1, y] = [x_2, y] = y^2 = 1 \rangle,
\end{equation}
then $G/G' \cong \mathbf{Z}^2$, and $G_{1} \cong \mathbf{Z}$, and $G$ has torsion.

Comment: yes, of course, let me edit the question... I forgot to put one and important) constraint on the relations.

Comment: Ah, ok, looking forward to the revised version.

Comment: Do you allow $j = k$ in the second type of relations? I'm not sure it makes a difference, but just to be sure.

Comment: no, it is not allowed (added that, thanks).

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about torsion elements but your quotient seems a bit off to me. Setting one of the generators to the identity simply gives you a free group on n-1 generators.